# json.Marshal for http post request with echo

Tags: go

I have two golang servers running on localhost.

They are using different ports.

I want to create a post request on one that sends a JSON object to the other one.

I am using the echo framework (if this matters)

The error I am getting is when I try to marshal the object for the post object:

```
2-valued json.Marshal(data) (value of type ([]byte, error)) where single value is expected
```

server 1:

```
type SendEmail struct {
    SenderName       string `json:"senderName,omitempty" bson:"senderName,omitempty" validate:"required,min=3,max=128"`
    SenderEmail      string `json:"senderEmail" bson:"senderEmail" validate:"required,min=10,max=128"`
    Subject          string `json:"subject" bson:"subject" validate:"required,min=10,max=128"`
    RecipientName    string `json:"recipientName" bson:"recipientName" validate:"required,min=3,max=128"`
    RecipientEmail   string `json:"recipientEmail" bson:"recipientEmail" validate:"required,min=10,max=128"`
    PlainTextContent string `json:"plainTextContent" bson:"plainTextContent" validate:"required,min=10,max=512"`
}

func resetPassword(c echo.Context) error {

email := c.Param("email")
    if email == "" {
        return c.String(http.StatusNotFound, "You have not supplied a valid email")
    }

    data := SendEmail{
        RecipientEmail:   email,
        RecipientName:    email,
        SenderEmail:      “test@test”,
        SenderName:       “name”,
        Subject:          "Reset Password",
        PlainTextContent: "Here is your code to reset your password, if you did not request this email then please ignore.",

    }

// error here
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "127.0.0.1:8081/", json.Marshal(data))

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer req.Body.Close()

    return c.JSON(http.StatusOK, email)
}
```

server 2:

**e.GET("/", defaultRoute)**

```
func defaultRoute(c echo.Context) (err error) {


    u := SendEmail{}
    if err = c.Bind(u); err != nil {
        return
    }

    return c.JSON(http.StatusOK, u)
}
```

Comment: The `json.Marshal` function retruns **two** values, therefore Go does not allow you to pass the result of that function call directly to `http.NewRequest("POST", "<url>", <body>)`. First assign the result to some variables, make sure to check the error variable (the 2nd of the two returned values) and if all's good, pass the 1st variable, the marshaled data, to `NewRequest` as the body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's always nice to meet a Gopher. A few things you might want to know, Go supports multi-value returns in that a function can return more than one value.

```
byteInfo, err := json.Marshal(data) // has two values returned
// check if there was an error returned first
if err != nil{
  // handle your error here
}
```

Now the line below in your code

```
// error here
req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "127.0.0.1:8081/", json.Marshal(data))
```

Will become this

```
// error here
req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "127.0.0.1:8081/", bytes.NewBuffer(byteInfo))
```

And you can continue with the rest of your code. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 2):

`json.Marshal` returns `[]byte` and `error` which means you're passing 4 values to `http.NewRequest`.

You should call `json.Marshal` first and then use the result for `http.NewRequest`.

```
body, err := json.Marshal(data)
if err != nil {
 // deal with error
}
req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "127.0.0.1:8081/", body)
```